# Появились лишние слайды

Tags: html, slider, popup, magnific

Использую слайдер lightSlider и одновременно magnific-popup(что бы картинка открывалась в модальном окне). И произошла такая проблема, добавил всего два слайда, а при открытии этих слайдов в модальном окне, появляются их дубликаты и слайдов становится 4. Можете подсказать в чем проблема, сам никак не могу додуматься. Приложил скриншоты для наглядности. Если что-то не внятно написал, то готов дополнить.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="col-md-12 item_001 active">        
        <div id="item_001">
          <div class="col-md-6 img_block_width ">                  
            <ul id="imageGallery" class="image-link">                  
              <a href="/img/kolekc/sensa/big_33798_724.jpg" data-thumb="/img/kolekc/sensa/big_33798_724.jpg"><img src="/img/kolekc/sensa/big_33798_724.jpg" alt=""></a> 
              <a href="/img/kolekc/sensa/big_33800_634.jpg" data-thumb="/img/kolekc/sensa/big_33800_634.jpg"><img src="/img/kolekc/sensa/big_33800_634.jpg" alt=""></a>  
              <a href="/img/kolekc/sensa/big_33798_724.jpg" data-thumb="/img/kolekc/sensa/big_33798_724.jpg"><img src="/img/kolekc/sensa/big_33798_724.jpg" alt=""></a>                   
            </ul>     
          </div> 
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <table class="table">                 
              <tbody> 
                <tr>
                  <th class="border_none">Артикул</th>
                  <td class="border_none">33798</td>                      
                </tr>                   
                <tr>
                  <th>Коллекция</th>
                  <td>Colonial Vintage</td>                      
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Длина</th>
                  <td>1286 мм</td>                      
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Ширина</th>
                  <td>194 мм</td>                      
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Толщина</th>
                  <td>8 мм</td>                      
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Метраж пачки</th>
                  <td>D1,996 м2</td>                      
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Количество досок в пачке</th>
                  <td>8</td>                      
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Количество пачек в паллете</th>
                  <td>56</td>                      
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Замок</th>
                  <td>Megaloc</td>                      
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Структура</th>
                  <td>Хром зона</td>                      
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Фаска</th>
                  <td>4V</td>                      
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>Класс</th>
                  <td>32/АС4</td>                      
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th class="border_bot">Плотность плиты HDF</th>
                  <td class="border_bot">870 кг/м3</td>                      
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div> 
        </div>            
  </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image-link').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type:'image',
    gallery:{
        enabled:true
    }
});
```

});

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#imageGallery').lightSlider({
    gallery:true,
    item:1,
    loop:true,
    thumbItem:9,
    slideMargin:0,
    enableDrag: false,
    currentPagerPosition:'left',
    onSliderLoad: function(el) {
        el.lightGallery({
            selector: '#imageGallery .lslide'
        });
    }   
});
```

});

Comment: скиньте код в печатном виде + не забудьте так же js добавить

Comment: `Ctrl+C` -> `Ctrl+V` - это вся сложность в нормальном оформлении вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как отметил уже сам ТС, в подобных слайдерах (light, slick, etc) присутствует параметр `loop`, отвечающий за бесконечную цикличность слайдов. При значении `true` скрипт слайдера множит слайды, отсюда и "проблемы".

Answer (score 0):

Решил. Поставил в скрипте у слайдера `loop: false`.

Comment: @entithat К сожалению лучших ответов нет. И да, это ТС.